# Google Maps API Android Issue

Tags: android, google-maps

so I'm currently developing my first app. I'm just creating a simple map app with different markers on it.
So it's all working perfectly well in the emulator. But when I run the published .apk on my phone, the map doesn't show. It has the GUI but there aren't any continents.
Does this have something to do with the API I got?
Note: I'm running the app on my Samsung Galaxy S6.

Answer (score 1):

You need a new API key (generated with a release certificate) for the signed apk. Simply follow instructions on this page: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup?hl=en#release-cert

You'll find information you need under `Display your app's certificate information` title, `RELEASE CERTIFICATE` section.

Comment: Hi @James99, happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.